# Convert into affine form

Tags: linear-algebra

I've $x+y=y+z=\frac{x+z}{2}$ and want that on affine form or in $(x,y,z) - t (a,b,c)$. I know it should be really simple but I don't find anywhere how to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $x+y=y+z$ gives $x=z$ which you may as well call another name $u$. Then the equation $y+z=(x+z)/2$ becomes $y+u=(u+u)/2=u$. This then gives $y=0$, so what is known about $x,y,z$ is only that $x=z$ and $y=0$. If you change to $t$ for the common value of $x,z$ then $(x,y,z)=(t,0,t)=t(1,0,1)$ and maybe what you're looking for is the form $(x,y,z)-t(1,0,1)$ which will be zero on (and only on) the solution set of your equations.